# Break function does not work when the elif line is true

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

```
start = input('Enter quadratic equation: ')
w = start.split()
while len(w) != 7:
    start = input('Enter quadratic equation correctly: ')
    w = start.split()
while x < len(w):
        if "x" in w[x] and '^2' in w[x]:
            a = w[x]
            if a == "x^2":
                a = 1
            else:
                a = a.replace('x^2', '')
                a = int(a)
            if w[x-1] == '-':
                a = a * (-1)
            else:
                a = a
        elif 'x' in w[x] and '^' not in w[x]:
            b = w[x]
            if b == 'x':
                b = 1
            else:
                b = b.replace('x', '')
                b = int(b)
            if w[x-1] == '-':
                b = b * (-1)
            else:
                b = b
        elif w[x].isdigit() and 'x' not in w[x] and w[x] != '0':
            c = w[x]
        elif w[x] == '-' or '+' or '=':
            s = 0
        elif not w[x].isdigit() and 'x' not in w[x] and w[x] != '-' or '+' or '=':
            print('Mistake')
            break #Would not this code here work?
        x += 1
```

I have tried just doing 'else' block, but still it wouldn't work. What I am trying to do is to check whether the input is actually a quadratic equation.

Comment: Can you share how exactly you write your quadratic equation ?

Comment: Example: 3x^2 + 12x + 13 = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong condition is `elif not w[x].isdigit() and 'x' not in w[x] and w[x] != '-' or '+' or '=':`, it doesn't do what you want/need

---

The `w[x] != '-' or '+' or '=':` part :

- **is like** `(w[x]!='-')   or   ('+')   or   ('='):`
- **not like** `w[x]   !=   ('-' or '+' or '='):`

---

What you want is `w[x] not in '-+='`: and same for the previous one

```
    elif w[x] in '-+=':
        s = 0
    elif not w[x].isdigit() and 'x' not in w[x] and w[x] not in '-+=':
        print('Mistake')
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! But still it does not print 'Mistake' after I enter 'a a a a a a a'

Comment: @EgorK Just saw that the one before it was wrong for the same reason, look my edit

Comment: @EgorK You can think about voting up the answer, ans accept it (green tick on left) if it satisfies you ;)